# How to handle varbinary columns in repodb queries?

Tags: c#, repodb

In a project includes RepoDB, it is used by queries but I have problem with varbinary columns.

```
Dictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
param.Add("MyContent", myObject.MyContent));
var sql = "INSERT INTO mytable(myvarbinarycolumn) values (@MyContent);
await connection.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(sql, param);
```

I got the error:

```
'The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.'
```

`myObject.MyContent` is a byte array but I tried also using string and encoding.

I already solved using classes and

```
connection.InsertAsync(myObject);
```

But I would like to know if there is a solution using queries and parameters.

EDIT: The question is about RepoDB, so using DbCommand or other ORM is not an option.

Comment: I would expect `TypeMapper.Add<byte[]>(DbType.Binary, true)` to be a default, but in case it's not it's worth trying. Another option is to explicitly use `new SqlBinary(myObject.MyContent)` for the parameter, but that does more or less defeat the purpose of using an ORM and you may in that case as well use regular old `DbCommand`s and `DbParameter`s (which is another option, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `SqlBinary` (thanks to @Jeroen):

```
param.Add("MyContent", myObject.MyContent == null ? DBNull.Value : new SqlBinary(myObject.MyContent ));
```

Comment: Note that `SqlBinary` does tie you to SQL Server -- if that's not desirable, the obvious alternative would be declaring a `record BinaryBlob(byte[] Value)` yourself and using the same solution as for classes (`TypeMapper.Add<BinaryBlob>(e => e.Value, DbType.Binary)`). You would then use `new BinaryBlob(myObject.MyContent)` for the parameter instead. Though it would be a bit surprising if RepoDB doesn't already have a solution along those lines itself; I'd say not treating `byte[]` special qualifies as a bug.

Comment: I can't find BinaryBlob. I need to understand if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

When passing an array to the parameters and if you use the `Execute` method, RepoDB will execute an array based parameters and not passing that array to the target column. See this [link](https://repodb.net/operation/executenonquery#array-parameters-for-the-in-keyword).

To solve this, you have to pass the proper value type to the list of argument like what you did above via `new SqlBinary`.

```cs
var param = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "Value", new SqlBinary(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WhateverValue")) }
};
var sql = "INSERT INTO [TestTable]([Value]) VALUES (@Value);";
var result = connection.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, param);
```